# soup.find_all,returns empty even if parser works, url is correct

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

```
textToSearch = 'python tutorials'
query = urllib.parse.quote(textToSearch)
url = "https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=" + query
response = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
html = response.read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
for vid in soup.findAll(attrs={'class':'yt-uix-tile-link'}):
    if not vid['href'].startswith("https://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/"):
        print('https://www.youtube.com' + vid['href'])
```

i am trying to get the first vieo url of a query without using the youtube data v3 api due to its limit

returns empty even if parser works, url is correct

using python 3.9.0

Answer (score 1):

the youtube data is now in a JSON object instead of being embedded into the HTML of the search page so beautiful soup can't access it

for youtube, to solve the issue i used a library called youtube-search

Answer (score 0):

the method that i use is soup.find_all, not soup.findAll